# What explains past affinities of minor coalition members in Ireland?

Tags: parties, republic-of-ireland, coalition

Looking at [prior governing coalitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_cabinets_since_1919) in Ireland, it seems that FG was more likely to have Labour as their minor partner, and FF was more likely to have the Greens. If this is correct, are there some explanations for these affinities?

(Neither of these historical coalitions by itself has a majority in the current [near] "three-way tie" Dáil, by the way.)

Comment: Labour has been the third party for a long time. The greens only got into power once.

Comment: Fianna Fáil appears to have more of an affinity with the (now defunct) Progressive Democrats than with Greens (only in coalition with Greens once) and have often been big enough to go by themselves. I'd imagine the Fine Gael-Labour coalitions were often the result of the second and third opposition parties being big enough when combined to form a government when FF could not.